# Meteor js not responding

Tags: meteor

I have been working with meteor.js and have been practicing using examples from getting started with meteor.js Javascript framework. The book is 2 years old and I have been running across some snags. For instance the book tells you to use var to define a variable, but after searching on stack I read that you didn't have to use it and now it works. I'm new so I write programs, run them, debug them and start from scratch to help me learn. For some reason this program that I have done 4 times before today is not running and I cant figure out why.

I keep getting this message :

```
While building the application:

LendLib.html:37: Expected "template" end tag
...             ï¿¼ </div>
```

after inputting the following code:

```
<head>
    <title>LendLib</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
  <div id="categories-container">
    {{> categories}}
  </div>
</body>
<template name="hello">
  <h1>Lending Library</h1>{{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
  <template name="categories">
      <div class="title">my stuff</div>
      <div id="categories">{{#each lists}}
          <div class="category">{{Category}}</div>{{/each}} ￼</div>
  </template>
</template>
```

any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont define templates inside another template.
try like this.

```
<template name="hello">
    <h1>Lending Library</h1>
    {{greeting}}
    <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
<template name="categories">
    <div class="title">my stuff</div>
    <div id="categories">
        {{#each lists}}
        <div class="category">
            {{Category}}
        </div>
        {{/each}} ￼
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like pahan said, you cannot define a template within another template. They each have to be separate and un-nested. You CAN, however, *call* a template from within another template.

```
<template name="myOtherTemplate">

  <h1> Lalalala </h1>

</template>

<template name="myTemplate">

{{> myOtherTemplate}} //injects the contents of myOtherTemplate

</template>
```

On another note, you also cannot nest `Template` instances within other `Template` instances.

Say that you want to register a helper function only after a certain template has been rendered.

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function({

  Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    key: "value",
    anotherKey: "anotherValue"
  });

});
```

^^ This also won't work.